# C# Windows Form App (Private deployment of SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2) Error - Stopped working

Tags: c#, deployment, sql-server-ce, compact-database

This is my 1st time deploying a C# project.

- dev machine x64
- targeted machine x86

Setup Project Launch Condition

- .NET Framework 4

According to http://erikej.blogspot.com/2012/05/private-deployment-of-sql-server.html

applications targeting .NET 4.0, either .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 or the VC++ 2005 SP1 redistributable (for x86 and/or x64) is required.

So I have downloaded and installed VC++ 2005 SP1 redistributable x86 on client machine
and since it is win 7 it includes .NET 3.5 SP1

I have published the app and even created the setup project It installs in the targeted machine without any problem but when I try to run the installed app it give me the following error.

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: automobile repairs system.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 52845d57
  Problem Signature 04: System.Data.SqlServerCe
  Problem Signature 05: 3.5.1.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4b743b2d
  Problem Signature 07: 15c
  Problem Signature 08: 12
  Problem Signature 09: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCe
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

When developing I followed [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33661/Creating-a-Private-Installation-for-SQL-Compact)

And I **didn't use Entity Framework 4**

for weeks I've been referring to lots of articles but STILL no luck.

I even search online a solution but nothing actually works

- I cleaned the registry and reinstalled the app
- Tried uninstalling and restart the machine and then again installing the app

but still I'm missing something.

When I check the installation directory in client machine it displays

- AMD64 folder with .dlls
- X86 folder with .dlls
- ARMS.sdf file
- System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

What am I doing wrong please help me out....
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally came up with the solution a very simple solution but took me some time.

First I installed Visual Studio to the client machine then I debugged the app which gave me the exact exception.
Then added a new code to print more details on the error then finally after understanding the exact issue causing the error "Cant access the .sdf" I changed the access property of the .sdf  to full control to the currently logged in profile and again when I run the app it gave me no errors :) For More details on how I solved it visit my [blog](http://cgtech6.blogspot.com/2013/11/c-windows-form-app-private-deployment.html)